# ExternalID need to be unique?

Tags: externalid, unique-field

I am trying to make a certain field an externalID,and the background job runs, and I never see the checbox get checked.  Originally, I was trying to make it both unique an an externalID, however, there are dupes in there and I was unable to make it unique....does an externalID need to be unique?  Or is there some other reason I am not seeing this box get checked? I even check the audit trail, and it shows me marking it as an external identifier. I am at my wits end.

Answer (score 1):

No, an externalId does not need to be unique.

There are benefits to an externalId being unique, such as being able to specify a record to be updated using the externalId instead of the standard Id field.

```
Account myAcc = new Account(myExternalIdField__c = '12345');

// This works as long as the given value of the externalId field is not duplicated
//   in any other Account record (on the same field)
// The 'unique' checkbox doesn't need to be checked to take advantage of this
update myAcc;
```

The 'unique' checkbox is basically adding a field constraint in the data store that underlays Salesforce.

You'll need to get rid of the duplicate ids that you have if you want to make the externalId field unique. I imagine Salesforce prevents you from doing this as a "save you from yourself" type thing. If you tried to make a field in a db unique where the existing data isn't unique, you'd get an error of some sort.

externalId is a property of the field itself (part of the field's metadata). It's generally something that you want to design into your system, not something to temporarily enable and then disable again.

Comment: Thanks @derek!  I am just not sure why it isn't showing up in the UI....I added up above that it shows me marking as External, and I get an email saying that it finishes....I am not sure where the disconnect is